# AWS - Assume IAM using PowerShell on an instance

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-powershell

This is more a sanity check because I've solved the problem but I'm unconvinced I've done it the smart way.

**The Problem**

I have some instances that have been assigned an IAM roles that allow them to access an S3 bucket. I then need to run some PowerShell scripts that will access that S3 bucket to download some objects.

**The Solution**

To get/set the credentials to use I've written this PowerShell function:

```powershell
function Set-MyInstanceProfileCredentials {

    param(
        [parameter()]
        [string]
        $StoredCredentialsName = "MyInstanceProfileCredentials"
    )

    $Uri = "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/"
    Write-Verbose "Retrieving instance profile from $($Uri)"
    $Uri = "$Uri$(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri)"
    Write-Verbose "Retrieving security credentials from $($Uri)"
    $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri
    Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey $Response.AccessKey -SecretKey $Response.SecretAccessKey -StoreAs $StoredCredentialsName
    Get-AWSCredentials -StoredCredentials $StoredCredentialsName
}
```

Then when I need to run a PowerShell cmdlet from the AWS module I just call this function first.

However I can't shake the feeling that I've missed something from the AWS PowerShell module that is already taking care of this for me.

Answer (score 3):

> However I can't shake the feeling that I've missed something from the AWS PowerShell module that is already taking care of this for me.

:) - you will be delighted to hear that this simply works out of the box indeed, i.e. the [AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/powershell/) is build upon the [AWS SDK for .NET](https://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/), which is handling this automatically, see also [Credentials Search Order](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html#pstools-cred-provider-chain):

> When you run a command, PowerShell Tools searches for credentials in the following order and uses the first available set.
>
> [...]
>
> 6) If you are using running the command on an Amazon EC2 instance that is configured for an IAM role, use EC2 instance credentials stored in an instance profile.
>
> For more information about using IAM roles for Amazon EC2 Instances, go to the [AWS Developer Guide for .NET](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/DeveloperGuide/net-dg-roles.html).